# jQuery - Find the last and before last row in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got the following html table :

```
<table id="jTable">

  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Competition</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>Paul</td>   
    </tr>   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Swimming</td>
    <td>1:30</td>
    <td>2:05</td>
    <td>1:15</td>
    <td>1:41</td>   
    </tr>   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Running</td>
    <td>15:30</td>
    <td>14:10</td>
    <td>15:45</td>
    <td>16:00</td>   
    </tr>   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>70%</td>
    <td>55%</td>
    <td>90%</td>
    <td>88%</td>   
    </tr>   <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>Blablabla</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>   </tr> 
</table>
```

What I'm trying to do is to hide all the rows except for the first, the before last and the last one. Here's how I'm doing :

```
$('#jTable').find('tr:gt(0):not(:last)').slideToggle();
```

This jQuery script only keeps the first and last row. Knowing the fact that I must use jQuery 1.7.1 (so I can't use the nth-last-child property), I was looking for a way to select the before last row.

Comment: Only do `$('#jTable tr:first').hide();` and `$('#jTable tr:last').hide();` two times. on `:last` first time hides 1st last then 2nd last will be your last and `hide` that also. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the `last` and `before last` `tr` using `eq()` function like following.

```
var len = $('#jTable tr').length;
var first_row = $('#jTable tr').eq(0); 
var last_row = $('#jTable tr').eq(len - 1);
var before_last_row = $('#jTable tr').eq(len - 2);
```

**Update**

```
$('#jTable tr').not(first_row).not(last_row).not(before_last_row).slideToggle();
```

Comment: Before `downvoting` please let me know what is my problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, how should I use the variable into find() function ?

Comment: You don't need to use find. You can use `not` instead. See updated answer. @Traffy

Comment: I don't blame you :). I ask the downvoter for my problem. @ParthTrivedi

Comment: Thanks ! However, I need to keep the first row too in my case. Is that still possible?

Comment: Of course. Just use `eq(0)`. See updated answer. @Traffy

Answer (score 2):

Take these into a function and try.

```css
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#jTable tr:first').slidetoggle()
 $('#jTable tr:last').slidetoggle()
 $('#jTable tr:last').prev().slidetoggle()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, how should I use the variable into find() function ?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `find()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#jTable tr").not($("#jTable tr:first")).not($("#jTable tr:last").prev()).slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="jTable">

  <tr>
    <td>No</td>
    <td>Competition</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Adam</td>
    <td>Robert</td>
    <td>Paul</td>   
    </tr>   <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Swimming</td>
    <td>1:30</td>
    <td>2:05</td>
    <td>1:15</td>
    <td>1:41</td>   
    </tr>   <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Running</td>
    <td>15:30</td>
    <td>14:10</td>
    <td>15:45</td>
    <td>16:00</td>   
    </tr>   <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>Shooting</td>
    <td>70%</td>
    <td>55%</td>
    <td>90%</td>
    <td>88%</td>   
    </tr>   <tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>Blablabla</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td>1000</td>   </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: @Traffy Please check my answer. Run snippet.

Comment: Thanks ! However, I need to keep the first row too in my case. Is that still possible?

Comment: please give me what row you need?  `:first`? then exclude that line from my code.

Comment: @Traffy have you run snippet?